# How can I display a single post while they are giving me the error (No post found matching the query)

Tags: python, django

I am working with a django project to design a blog app. I am at the stage of displaying the posts, but I tried to display a single post (127.0.0.1:8000/post/1/), but I met error below:

*
Page not found (404)

Request Method: GET

Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/1/

Raised by:  rymapp.views.PostDetailView

No post found matching the query

*

**
See my views.py
**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Post



def home(request):
    return render(request, 'rymapp/home.html', {'title': 'home'})

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'rymapp/about.html', {'title': 'about'})

def blog(request):
    context = {
        'posts': Post.objects.all() 
    }
    return render(request, 'rymapp/blog.html', context)


class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'rymapp/blog.html' #<app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
```

Below is my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import PostListView, PostDetailView
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='rymapp-home'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='rymapp-about'),
    path('blog/', PostListView.as_view(), name='rymapp-blog'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='rymapp-post_detail'),
]
```

And here it is my post_detail.html

```
{% extends "rymapp/base.html" %}
{% block content %}

    <article class="media content-section mt-2">
        <div class="media-body">
            <lu class="list-group mr-5">
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">
                    <div class="article-metadata">
                        <img class="rounded-circle article-img" width="50" height="50" src="{{ object.author.profile.image.url }}">
                        <a class="mr-2 ml-2" href="#"> {{ object.author }} </a>
                        <small class="text-muted"> {{ object.date_posted | date:"F d, Y" }} </small>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">
                    <h2 class="article-title"> {{ object.title }} </h2>
                    <p class="article-content"> {{ object.content }} </p>
                </li>
            </lu>
        </div>
    </article>

{% endblock content %}
```

Please help me to fix this error.

Thank you so much for your time to consider my problem and help me.

Comment: It means there is no `Post` record in the database with primary key `1`.

Comment: do you have the post with ID `1` in the database?

Comment: can you please add the screenshot of your browser error page? By this maybe we easily understand your question.

Comment: @EbrahimKarimi, not only 1, even when I type post/4 or any number, they give me the same error. 

So, how can I add the post pk in the database at this stage?

Comment: how can I add the post pk in the database at this stage? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: it's not database problem, it's your routing problem (regex url patterns) try  to comment the first line which is `path('', views.home, name='rymapp-home'),` and tell me if it works

Comment: @EbrahimKarimi, when I comment the first line like you told me and later try to reload again, it is not working. I got the problem as below:

``
NoReverseMatch at /blog/
Reverse for 'rymapp-home' not found. 'rymapp-home' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/
Django Version: 3.1.2
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value: 
Reverse for 'rymapp-home' not found. 'rymapp-home' is not a valid view function or 
``

Comment: would you mind edit your question with a screenshot instead of copying the stacktrace

Comment: Oh yes, it would be better, but since I am new member on this platform, i don't know how to post the picture (screenshot) here. I tried to do it, but let me try it again, I think soon will work properly and get help from you on my Question. 
thank you!